# Starting Mysql in OSX 10 (no brew, no daemon, just a simple start)

Tags: mysql

I don't want to install MySQL on my computer, I don't want to change configuration of my OS, I want just start the mysql process writing the db on a local folder given from parameters.

I downloaded the mysql bundle from the mysql web site, and tried to start it using the **mysqld** command inside the *bin* folder in this way:

```
./bin/mysqld -b /Users/me/tools/mysql-5.6.28-osx10.10-x86_64 -h ~/Projects/my-project/db
```

But I have this error when it executes:

```
2016-01-25 11:13:24 33251 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

Everyone can read and write in the *db* folder, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I found this page in the mysql doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-installation.html.

To create and start a new db is needed to execute `mysql_install_db` (before Mysql v5.7.6) using the appropriate *datadir* and *basedir*.

In MySQL 5.6 the script is located under the **scripts** folder, not in the **bin** folder as is wrote in the docs.